# how to not include page in history BUT sometimes include it?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a edit form page and if the user clicks cancel, they go back to whatever page they came from with...

Cancel

QUESTION 1. How do I not only move back in the history, but pop my page as well so there is no forward button anymore
QUESTION 2. How do I do that same thing BUT I want my page included in the history when they hit the save button.

ie. a solution should work for #1 and #2.  Is that even possible?

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [HTML5 history API](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html). It covers both #1 and #2.